# How to bypass facebook login screen while integrating facebook to App

Tags: android, facebook

I had a situation where my application provides emailid and password and onclick of a  button  should perform facebook authentication and give the result back to app with out showing facebook login screen.
 can anyone help me how can this be achieved in android facebook integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s not possible at all, you have to implement an authorization/login process.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Even I gone through the SDK in detail after posting the question where I found the same info given by you . Thanks for the info once again .